# Mongo/mongoose unique works every other time

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, unique

I'm writing a subdomain string to a Mongodb database (run on Compose.io), and I need to ensure that the subdomain.name string is unique.

I setup my document as

```
var SubdomainModel = function() {
    var subdomainSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        name: {type: String, require: true, index: true, unique: true,  lowercase: true, trim: true},
        createdBy: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, require: true, ref: 'User'}
    });

    subdomainSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
        var subdomain = this;
        subdomain.name = subdomain.name.toLowerCase();
        next();
    });

    return mongoose.model('Subdomain', subdomainSchema);
}

module.exports = new SubdomainModel();
```

I'm using frisby.js to run my tests (it's based on jasmine). In my test, I delete the subdomain document, then create new subdomains. 
I also timestamp the subdomain name so I can make sure it is unique. I create the subdomain, then wait 15 seconds and create it again and ensure that my 2nd create call fails.

The test passes one time, then I re-run and it fails the next. When I look in the db, sure enough, there are two entries for the same subdomain.

```
{ name: "test-1425876399170", _id: ObjectId("54fd25af5ce2db7c0a7192d1"), __v: 0 }
{ name: "test-1425876399170", _id: ObjectId("54fd25be5ce2db7c0a7192d3"), __v: 0 }
```

Maybe the problem is being caused by the db being blown away, I'm not sure, but I'm amazed at how consistently it fails/passes/fails/passes.

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: At a guess I would say you are dropping the database or collection at the start of your test. Just remove documents instead, as the former will likely not time well with index creation. That happens on start up and not as collections are created.

Comment: Thanks Neil, you are correct, I am dropping the collection. I've changed the `drop()` request to be a `remove({})`, but I'm still seeing the same behavior.

Comment: At another guess I'd say you are still leaving data in there at some point of creation. For testing purposes ( not advised for production ) you can look at the [dropDups](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-creation/#drop-duplicates) option to avoid index creation failing. But once you stop messing around with dropping the collection or database, the `.ensureIndex()` methods should not be touching indexes once they exist anyway.

Comment: There is no data in the database, at the start of the test, I run the `remove`, then, in quick succession, the test, using a timestamped value, creates the document twice. I've put a 3 second timeout on the creation, but it sill creates duplicates on alternate runs. The reason I'm trying to create the same value twice is to make sure my app responds with the correct 'name already exists' value. 

I'm not running the `.ensureIndex` method. Should I be? If so, where? I'm using mongoose in express.

Comment: Mongoose runs `.ensureIndex()`  on all listed indexes for models on start-up automatically unless you tell it not to. The point here is something is removing the index or it is otherwise failing to create. That was why you needed to remove drop operations. A `.remove()` will not drop the indexes. You need to check for other causes where you might still be doing something that drops the index. It's the only reason this happens.

Comment: Unfortunately, the only place I'm doing any type of delete or remove is in that one place. So not sure why that is happening, but you've given me a few things to look into.